# _.startswith() overides the variable _

Tags: python-3.x

Is the behaviour described below by purpose (Python 3.7) ?

```
_ = '==TEST=='
_.startswith('==')
Out[29]: True
_
Out[30]: True

l = '==TEST=='
l.startswith('==')
Out[26]: True
l
Out[27]: '==TEST=='
```

I know the variable names are a poor choice but why does the call to `.startswith` override the variable `_` ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you run python in interactive mode it stores the value of each expression you evaluate into the underscore variable.

Comment: I thought that was an IPython specific thing. TIL

Comment: I was running it in an Ipython console within PyCharm